# Fatal error while using zend_json : not found

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, wamp

Trying to have a look on `zend2` I'm working on the `zend skeleton`.

On the Controller, I'm adding the following code:

```
// Decode JSON objects as PHP objects
$data = $request->getPost('album');
$result = Zend\Json\Json::decode($data);   // line 82
```

And I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Album\Controller\Zend\Json\Json' not found in C:\wamp\www\zf2-skeleton\module\Album\src\Album\Controller\AlbumController.php on line 82

Having a look on the official documentation, but I don't find anything that help me.

Maybe can you help me to understand what is missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a *qualified (relative) name* so PHP assumes `Zend\Json\Json` is within your namespace (ie `\Album\Controller`).

You need to prefix the entire inline name with a backslash to create a *fully qualified name*, eg

```
$result = \Zend\Json\Json::decode($data);
```

Otherwise, you can add the appropriate `use` statement at the top of your file (under the `namespace` section)...

```
use Zend\Json\Json;
```

and simply use the class name in your code...

```
$result = Json::decode($data);
```

See http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.basics.php